# Why does Redis memory usage shows high fluctuation?

Tags: memory, redis

I'm observing an odd behavior in Redis memory usage. I'm constantly inserting data into Redis and monitoring the number of keys and memory usage. The number of keys does increase as expected but the memory usage does not make any sense to me. It increases smoothly but once in a while it shows a  big fluctuation ranging from a few megabytes to more than a gigabyte and then continues increasing smoothly again. Fluctuation usually continues for a few minutes.

Can anyone please explain why these fluctuations happen?

The following images shows when the memory usage is changing from stable to fluctuation, during fluctuation and when going back from fluctuation to stable
[image]
[image]
[image]
The time axis is per 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Are you using any expiry on the keys? And what is the maxmemory set on your Redis?

Comment: @AnkitSahay No I'm not using any expiry on the keys. I also have not set any limit for maxmemory.